# MPI : Communication error with rank 1: Connection refused

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a simple mpi program as follows :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    MPI::Init(argc, argv);

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int number;
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        number = -1;
        MPI_Send(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else if (world_rank == 1) {
        MPI_Recv(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                 MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("Process 1 received number %d from process 0\n",
               number);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I have specified a host file which includes 2 entries. Server is the local machine i am running mpi on and ubuntu is the remote machine.

```
Server
ubuntu
```

When i try to run the mpi executable by running `mpirun -np 2 --hostfile hosts ./test` it gives me an error `Communication error with rank 1: Connection refused`. However if i reverse the order of hosts in my host file

```
ubuntu
Server
```

It works fine. I cannot seem to understand why. Does the order of the hosts in the hosts file matter?

Comment: What is your MPI implementation and which version is it. Please tell us more about your installation and which steps you have taken so far.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the order of the hosts in the hosts file was used by your MPI implementation to determine rank. If this is the case, then what is happening is that one of your machines can send messages just fine, but can't receive them. This is likely due to overly restrictive firewall settings.

Comment: Your code runs fine here...

Comment: @Zulan: I am using  MPICH version 3.0.4. I installed it using "sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc". I have created an mpiuser and have followed this tutorial (http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/) to set up a cluster of 2 nodes.

Comment: @R_Kapp: If the order is as i have explained of ubuntu,server it means that my server has a firewall problem? How can i correct this?

Comment: https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions Q: My MPI program aborts with an error saying it cannot communicate with other processes. Also please edit your question to include the requested additional information, so that it is a useful question without reading the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I've happened to face the same issue as you did in run time error.

After you've make sure you can ssh and login to your clients machine **without passwords**.  The main reason for the MPICH master can't find the client(slave)'s hostname is because the client in `/etc/hosts file`, the localhost name is assign both to the client user name and to the localhost itself, e.g. run `sudo vim etc/hosts` you will have the hosts name list for your machine:

```
127.0.0.1 clientUsrName
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

the order doesn't matter at all. All you have to do is to comment your clientUsrName wrong refered to the 127.0.0.1 as the localhost IP. For example:

```
# 127.0.0.1 clientUsrName
127.0.0.1 localhost
```